# Bound on computing joint probability

Tags: integration

Say we have a joint density:
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\frac{21}{2}x^2y$$
Where the range of $x$ is $[0,\sqrt{y}]$ and the range of $y$ is $[0,1]$. We now need to find the probability of $P[0<X<0.25,\;\;0.25<Y<1]$.

My intuition is to do a double integral on the joint density. the bound of $y$ is easy, it is just from $0$ to $1$, however the bound of $x$ is eating me, My guess is I should put $[0.5,1]$ for x because when $y$ ranges in $[0.25,1]$; $\sqrt{y}$ ranges in $[0.5,1]$. However, we want to probability if $X$ ranges from $0$ to $0.25$!, it does not fall into the range of $\sqrt{y}$...Thus I guess the answer is $0$, but I'm pretty much sure this answer is wrong...Please tell me how I can attack this problem, any help is appreciated! thank you!

Comment: This isn't right. The easiest way to tell would be to draw the boundaries on top of the support of the density function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bounds for the relevant probabilities lie completely with in the parabola shape without intersecting it, making the bounds simply a rectangle:

$$\int_{0.25}^1 \int_0^{0.25}\frac{21}{2}x^2y\:dx\:dy = \frac{105}{2^{12}}$$

The total support for the probability distribution is bounded by the red, black and blue curves. The rectangle we need for the problem is entirely within this region.

[image]